# React Router V6 - Opening a Modal with the parent element loaded in the background

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make an https://unsplash.com/ clone and I'm stuck on the modal part.

I want when clicking an image, a modal pop out and display the content with the gallery in the background as well as the url to change .

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
    <Navbar />
    <Routes >
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
           <Route index element={<ImagesContainer />}></Route>            
        </Route>
        <Route path='/videos' element={<VideoContainer />}></Route>

        <Route path='/:type/:id' element={<ImagePopup />} />
     </Routes>
```

Comment: Consider using a component library: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal_overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal_container{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 450px;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: #404752;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
const Modal = ( props:{closeFunction:() => void, children?: React.ReactNode) => {
```

```
return (
        <div className={styles.modal_overlay} onClick={props.closeFunction}>
            <div className={styles.modal_container} onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}}  style={props.style}>
                
                <div className={styles.modal_content} style={props.contentStyle}>
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

```
}
```

> Open or close it with an useState

I get somenthing like this:
[My Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9MhM.png)